# Get data from other column details

Tags: php, mysql

My table looks like this:

```
check_in_id | amount | date | user_id (foreign key of user table )
```

In the interface it asks user to enter `amount`, `date`, `username`, `password`.  When running the `insert into` query, how do I get `user_id` from that user table to insert into this table?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: You ought to already know the user_id at the point of displaying the form, otherwise how will you ever know who has made the action? Without more information, we can't give an answer. Are you using a framework, or rolling your own forms? Do you use any authentication method?

Comment: Who is `user`? Is it current user who logged in your site or does it come from other place? Usually you store `user_id` of logged in user in the session of your site ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have one main table (say: **tbl_login** ) to store **username, password, user_id** (primary key).

So, You first retrieve **user_id** with **username and password** like:

```
SELECT user_id FROM tbl_login WHERE username = '$username' AND password = 'password';
```

Where $username and $password is your entered username and password from interface.

So after getting **user_id** , now you have all needed values, so you can easily insert these in your given table.

Answer (score 0):

Since the information in you query is incomplete, I will try to give an answer with certain assumptions.

`check_in_id`: an auto increment id in

You want to insert into table only if username and password matches.

The variables with `'$'` are the user inputs

```
insert into <your table>
(check_in_id, amount, date, user_id)
select null, $amount, $date, user_id from user
where username = $username and password = $password
```